# Show data for previous date

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

How can I display for a given date (31-Jul-17) then on the second column, show data from one day previous (30-Jul-17)?

Comment: this you can easily done at database side by using procedure. other wise in report side its tedious job which is not recommended. So get data as you want at db side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write custom SQL for this, use a subreport. Create a small subreport in that column, which takes the original date in as a Parameter. Suppress everything inside that subreport except the Details section, or whatever you use in the main report.

Then have the subreport display the first record for that date minus one.

Comment: sub report will not help in this scenerio, how you understand that one to one record record will set with subreport and main report data

Comment: @Ajay2707 I can guarantee this is possible. Design the subreport such that its the same size as a field, and pass in the `LaterDate` and `MachineName` in as parameters. Then have the subreport only show one field, where the `MachineName` matches and the `PreviousDate` is equal to `LaterDate` - 1. Do not select Can Grow on the subreport.

Comment: just try dear. how you put sub-report in section with detail section or fotter section where your main data is repeated and sub-report with same line of data. just think and if you got idea , then tell me

Comment: @Ajay2707 You absolutely *can* put a subreport into the Details section. The idea is that this subreport repeats, for every record. And each time it repeats, it shows one record - That's all. I've done this countless times before, it's rather easy.